# RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED when calling `cublasCreate(handle)`

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, jupyter-lab

---

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_77/2707828773.py in <cell line: 8>()
30         #反向传播
31         optimizer.zero_grad()
---> 32         loss.backward()
33         optimizer.step()
34

~/.conda/envs/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs)
486                 inputs=inputs,
487             )
--> 488         torch.autograd.backward(
489             self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs
490         )

~/.conda/envs/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/autograd/**init**.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
195     # some Python versions print out the first line of a multi-line function
196     # calls in the traceback and some print out the last line
--> 197     Variable.*execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
198         tensors, grad_tensors*, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
199         allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass

my code is edited by SageMaker Studio Lab. i dont know what happen. how can i fix this error?